# Service Reference does not create 'specified' properties for DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, visual-studio-2013

I've added a Service Reference for a SOAP web service. The WSDL contains a few dateTime elements like:

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="plannedStartDate" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="plannedEndDate" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
```

etc. VS2013 generated a class with properties of (non-nullable) DateTime type, but did not add properties like plannedStartDateSpecified. As a result, I don't have the option to skip sending any of them. If I hack the generated code to be nullable DateTime? properties, it sends null in those fields, and the remote system nulls out the values as I'd expect. I need to skip sending the input elements entirely.

Creating a Web Reference does yield the "specified" properties, which allows me to skip sending optional elements and everything's good.

Any ideas? I'd like to use service references to keep everything consistent across our libraries which consume services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll wait and see if anyone has a more clever answer, but I punted and used svcutil.exe with XmlSerializer, and wrapped, as follows.

```
svcutil /serializer:XmlSerializer /namespace:*,<desired_namespace_for_generated_class> /wrapped <path_to_WSDL>
```

For convenience in app.config, I added a regular Service Reference in Visual Studio as usual for the same WSDL, then replaced the content of the VS-generated Reference.cs with the content of the file spawned from svcutil.exe. Now I have the *specified fields and everything works like I want it to.

Yeah, it's not too kosher to edit generated code, but this is a published, and versioned, web service. So I don't anticipate having to update the service reference (and therefore mess it up).

Comment: As an alternative to replacing the generated content, you can switch the Service Reference to XmlSerializer by editing the svcmap file's "<Serializer>" element to "XmlSerializer".

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be found here: [Binding to a SOAP Service With Optional Value Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743085/binding-to-a-soap-service-with-optional-value-types)

(Adding `<Wrapped>true</Wrapped>` to element `ClientOptions` in the generated Reference.svcmap file)

Comment: In general please try to answer with the content of a website rather than just a link in case the link becomes invalid in the future.