# Binding to a SOAP Service With Optional Value Types

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a method on a SOAP service being generated with the following `WSDL`:

```xml
<xs:complexType name="updateItem">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="itemCode" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="itemParentCode" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="itemStatus" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="isActive" type="xs:boolean" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="isPrimary" type="xs:boolean" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I'm connecting to this service and generating the client using Visual Studio in a .NET Framework 4.7 desktop application.

This generates a method with the following parameters:

```
public void updateItem(string itemCode, string itemParentCode, 
    string itemStatus, bool isActive, bool isPrimary)
```

According to the service definition, `isActive` and `isPrimary` are optional parameters, but in the generated method they are non-nullable value types.

Is there a way to generate the client to allow these to be optional, perhaps via nullable booleans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did finally find the answer to this question, but it does feel like the default behavior is a bug.  In the generated `Reference.svcmap` document, you can add a `<Wrapped>true</Wrapped>` to force the `*Specified` fields to show up.  You must add `Wrapped` under the `ClientOptions` node, like so:

```xml
<ClientOptions>
    <Wrapped>true</Wrapped>
</ClientOptions>
```

Regenerating the client now will force use of message contract objects, so the call will now look like this:

```c#
// Update an item
updateItem(new updateItem 
    { 
        itemCode = "testItem", 
        itemParentCode = "testParent", 
        itemStatus = "testStatus", 
        isActive = true, 
        isPrimary = true, 
        isActiveSpecified = true, 
        isPrimarySpecified = true 
    });
```

I'm relieved to have the solution, but still think this should be the default way of generating message contracts to allow for this scenario.